# Laravel route returns 302 instead of 404 response only during phpunit test

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-8

During a PHPUnit test a call should return a `404` error but instead it returns a `302` redirect.

Using [spatie permissions](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/introduction) to give users permissions.

The test:

```php
use RefreshDatabase;

public User $admin;

public function setUp(): void
{
      parent::setUp();

     $permission = Permission::firstOrCreate( [ 'name' => 'activities.delete' ] );
     $role = Role::firstOrCreate( [ 'name' => 'Admin' ] );
     $role->givePermissionTo( $permission );
     $this->admin = User::factory()->create();
     $this->admin->assignRole( 'Admin' );

     $this->app->make( PermissionRegistrar::class )->registerPermissions();
}

public function test_as_a_user_i_can_not_delete_activities_that_do_not_exist(): void
{
    Auth::login( $this->admin );

    $this->assertAuthenticatedAs( $this->admin );

     $response = $this->actingAs( $this->admin )
         ->delete( route( 'activities.destroy', 234234 ) );
      $response->assertNotFound();
}
```

Route:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::group( [ 'middleware' => 'auth' ], function()
{
    Route::group( [ 'prefix' => 'dashboard' ], function()
    {
        Route::resource( 'activities', \App\Http\Controllers\ActivityController::class )->except( [ 'show' ] );
     });
});
```

The delete function:

```php
public function destroy( Activity $activity ): RedirectResponse
{
     if( auth()->user()->customer )
     {
         abort( 403 );
     }

     $deleted = $activity->delete();

     return redirect()->route( 'activities.index' )->with( [
         'message' => 'Activity '.( $deleted ? 'deleted' : 'not deleted' ),
         'success' => $deleted,
     ] );
}
```

In development when deleting a non existing activity it is working as expected, it returns a 404 error. However during testing it returns a 302 redirect.

Also noticed that when deleting an existing activity during testing `dd($activity)` returns a blank model instead of the parsed `$activity` model. Again during development the parsed `$activity` is shown as expected.

```php
public function destroy( Activity $activity ): RedirectResponse
{
     if( auth()->user()->customer )
     {
         abort( 403 );
     }

     dd($activity);

     $deleted = $activity->delete();

     return redirect()->route( 'activities.index' )->with( [
         'message' => 'Activity '.( $deleted ? 'deleted' : 'not deleted' ),
         'success' => $deleted,
     ] );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class` middleware was missing in the `$middlewareGroups` `web` array in `App\Http\Kernel.php`.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#url-defaults-middleware-priority